# VBA Adding Row if certain Cell says "Yes"

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA coding and I would like to do the following.

I have an excel that has a row that has a dropdown list with "Yes" or "No" as an answer. The following photo shows what my excel sheet looks like at the moment and the 7th column is the one that has the drop-down list.
[image]

I would like to create a Macro that automatically inserts a row (underneath) if "Yes" is selected.

Once the "Yes" is selected I would like the new row to copy the information of the first 4 columns and leave the rest blank.

If "No" is selected, I would like nothing to happen!

Thank you!!

Edit: I have been able to create a simple code that inserts a row below, but I still am not able to copy and paste the information from the first 4 columns into the newly inserted row.

The code I used to insert a new row is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 8 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Target.Value = "Si" Then
            Rows(Target.Row + 1).Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a screenshot of your worksheet and elaborate on *information from a few columns...* and what should happen when `No` is selected.

Comment: @VBasic2008 i have added a screenshot!

Comment: Be careful, since those cells are merged, the value of the merged area is only contained in the top left cell. So to get the value of a merged range, you need to use `Range.MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value`. So for example, to get the value of the cell in column 1 above the new row, you would say `Cells(Target.Row, 1).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I have do some modification and able to insert new row afterand copy the value on new row also, however please take note there is some problem on your original code, `ThisRow`  was not declared as variable (Global variable?) and `xlFormatFromRightOrAbove` is not a valid method:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 8 Then
        'thisrow = Target.Row
        If Target.Value = "yes" Then
            Rows(Target.Row + 1).Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
            Range("A" & Target.Row, "G" & Target.Row).Copy Range("A" & Target.Row + 1, "G" & Target.Row + 1)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Yellow highlighted area is the new row, although you should avoid copy merge cell value

[image]